# Django media URL not found

Tags: python, django, django-media

I'm running into a strange issue,hope some where else some one can had faced the same problem.My problem which is like, the stored media in django application are not able to serve through MEDIA_ROOT URL.When I tried to get list of media files that are saved in my  application using URL myhost/media/ it showing all the media files.But when I tried to view on of them using URL myhost/media/image.jpg, got error Requested page not found.

Error Track Trace:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1.^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, ~myapp/media/image.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

My app settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/itsme/myapp/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can any one suggest me solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, try this: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` If you're using Django > 1.5

Comment: does that mean the problem is resolved?

Comment: @skzryzg No,problem is not resolved.

Comment: could you post your entire urls.py?

Comment: @Ramakrishna, "Not persisted" means the problem is no longer there.

Comment: how is the url `myapp/media/image.jpg` being generated?

Comment: @skzryzg   I am saving the image using this,models.ImageField(upload_to ="products/")

Comment: no, how is the url being generated?  if the image uploads to products/ then the url isnt being generated correctly.  it's lacking the absolute path, and it's lacking the product/ folder.Are you manually entering the image's path?

Comment: yes,I am manually entering the image's path

Comment: that method is more prone to human error and doesn't scale.  Use `<img src="{{image.url}}>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so many trails,finally I have fixed the issue.The problem is related to permission of media files.The process that's trying to access these media files is root and the files are owned by the user itsme. There's a kernel patch that prevents these type of accesses.So why 404 error is returning as response.