# How to change owner and group of an uploaded file in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, mod-wsgi

When I upload a file into Django server,the file permission seems to be like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bangtest nobody 5198 May  2 00:37 image.jpg
```

But I want to upload these files as root user,how can I do that using python in Django application.

I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994840/how-to-change-the-user-and-group-permissions-for-a-directory-by-name)

```
import pwd
import grp
import os

uid = pwd.getpwnam("root").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("root").gr_gid
path = '/home/bangtest/alpha/media/products/image_2081.jpg'
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

Then I am getting error like

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/bangtest/alpha/media/products/image_2081.jpg'

Suggest me a solution for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you change it to the root user?

Comment: Hello @François,Erlier I have faced a problem while accessing saved images from mod_wsgi apache,this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320821/django-media-url-not-found) is my problem.After changing the file owner from bangtest to root I am able to access the files.Because of that reason only I want to change it to the root user.

Comment: What is the process running as root that wants to access them? It wouldn't be Apache as when it is handling requests it is running as a different user and would never run as root. Any other process running as root should be able to access the files regardless of permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options, I always try these two:

1. Easy way: Set permissions to 775 in the folder you need to interact, or 777, if you need to save information (insecure).
2. Hard way: Add www/nobody or your apache's user name to your user group, and make the folder writable and readable for that group users (or simply add permissions for www or your apache/nginx user in that folder).